# Finding drivers for a new scanner

Tags: drivers, scanner, proprietary-drivers

I'm shopping for a document scanner. Some options are advertised as having drivers Windows and Mac. How can I know if it will run under Debian? I don't mind to install proprietary drivers, if I have to, but buying it just to discover it won't run sucks.

Comment: If it's TWAIN, it will work.

Comment: @ajeh: it is TWAIN. But how much tweaking will be necessary for it to work? Would it be kind of plug-n-play?

Comment: @ajeh AFAIK, TWAIN data sources are OS-specific. An alternative to SANE, sort of...

Answer (score 2):

The first place to check is SANE's list of supported devices, which you can access at http://www.sane-project.org/sane-supported-devices.html, both for the latest release and development versions. (Note at the moment the scanner search engine is broken; use the full lists instead).

Google is probably your best bet for finding if the manufacturer provides a proprietary driver. Also for finding other people's experience with the scanner on Linux.

If you're willing to pay for non-free scanner software, you could also check out VueScan which has an [extensive supported device list](https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/vuescan.htm#supported).

Comment: If you install a proprietary driver, then be prepared for you system to be unstable. Better to chose a scanner that is supported.